# No action after PHP form Posted to SQL

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a calendar of events, and the "details" for the event are on a hidden div.
I have a small icon that, when clicked, uses javascript to show the details.

What I want is that when this is clicked, the icon is replaced by a different icon (to show it is 'open') and for that icon, when clicked, to close the div again.

So the current code is

```
<a href="#" onclick="Effect.BlindDown('eventdetails<?php echo $event_count;?>'); return false;"><img class="open" src="./img/plus.png"></a>
```

And I'd want the image to change to "minus.png". So then it would be

```
<a href="#" onclick="Effect.BlindUp('eventdetails<?php echo $event_count;?>'); return false;"><img class="open" src="./img/minus.png"></a>
```

But cant quite figure it out. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Mia, got the following code to work. The button...

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggleDisplayWait('eventdetails<?php echo $event_count;?>', 'icon<?php echo $event_count;?>', 800); return false;"); return false;"><img id="icon<?php echo $event_count;?>" class="open" src="./img/plus.png"></a>
```

And in the header...

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    function toggleDisplayWait(divId, imgId, durationmSec) {
    if(!$(divId).visible()) {
        move = Effect.BlindDown;
        newImage = "./img/minus.png";
    }
    else {
        move = Effect.BlindUp;
        newImage = "./img/plus.png";  
    }        
    move(divId, {duration: durationmSec / 1000.0 });
    setTimeout(function() { $(imgId).src = newImage; }, durationmSec)
}

    </script>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with php, so I would remove that tag.  Can't help you with your problem though.  They use it on the php-manual-pages, you could check out how they do it with firebug or chrome developer tools.

They use jquery.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/heera/FJuqS/

Comment: @SheikhHeera, thanks for the response, but I'm not sure how to implement your suggestion.

Comment: I updated my answer, now you should call `<a href="#" onclick="toggleDisplayWait('eventdetails<?php echo $event_count;?>,'icon<?php echo $event_count;?>', 800); return false;">` and name your image id's to reflect event count. I am guessing there is more than one icon and you need to change the right one each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretend the kitties are a + sign, and the black image a -. I wrote two versions, in the first one (toggleDisplay), the image changes immediately. What you probably want is for the +/- to change only after the animation ends.

**EDIT** added arguments for div id and image id for multiple calendar days' divs. Otherwise the image id can be hardcoded inside the function. Also assuming all calendar dates use the same image for plus and minus.

Please take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/BfWUQ/3/

The div layout is jumpy but I imagine you have the layout figured out.

```
toggleDisplayWait('eventdetails', 'icon', 800);
// hidden div id, +/- image id, animation length in milliseconds

function toggleDisplayWait(divId, imgId, durationmSec) {
    if(!$(divId).visible()) {
        move = Effect.BlindDown;
        newImage = "http://placehold.it/100/100";
    }
    else {
        move = Effect.BlindUp;
        newImage = "http://placekitten.com/100/100";  
    }        
    move(divId, {duration: durationmSec / 1000.0 });
    setTimeout(function() { $(imgId).src = newImage; }, durationmSec)
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Change

```
onclick="toggleDisplayWait("eventdetails<?php echo $event_count;?>", 
"icon", 800); return false;"
```

to

```
onclick="toggleDisplayWait('eventdetails<?php echo $event_count;?>', 
'icon', 800); return false;"
```

Comment: Hi Mia, Huge thanks for the response. Unfortunately, what you wrote out for me isn't working. I'm wondering if this is because I was passing the name of the div inside the call itself? 
I'll edit above to clarify

Comment: @user1350192 You're right, you have to pass the div name into the function I wrote. I overlooked the php tag while writing the answer. So it should say `toggleDisplayWait(id, durationmSec)` and change the code inside. Hold on and I'll update the jsfiddle

Comment: @mercuryfrost OK, I made an edit to my answer. I'll be around for another hour.

Comment: many thanks. I've updated the original post with what I have. Unfortunately still not working. I'm sure I'm doing something small wrong. Really appreciating your time on this

Comment: @mercuryfrost I noticed one thing, when calling `toggleDisplayWait`, `icon` should be written `"icon"` since that's your image's id. Are you using the browser console to display warnings and errors? eventdetails should also be in quotes like your original code posted in the beginning of your question.

Comment: @mercuryfrost This time, you should change the " to ' inside the `onclick`. Otherwise the command string ends prematurely. I updated my answer.

Comment: NEARLY there! The icon doesn't change after the first event, but the button acts like it should

Comment: I guess that the `newImage` is pointing to something that doesn't exist? Or try removing the `setTimeout`. Hard for me to say. Are there any errors? Also does the Blinduo/down work properly? If not, there might be something wrong with my if statement.

Comment: BOOM! Fixed it. Had to give each event its own image id, despite the fact they were the same id. I'll post the final version in the original post. HUGE thanks Mia, I'd have been completely lost without you

Comment: Yeah, ids should be different. I don't think the browser complains, but behavior will be unexpected. Glad to help :)